# Matrix calculations using conditionals in R

Tags: r

I have a Matrix that is presented here through the `dput()` function.

```
Matrix <- structure(list(Int = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), Time = c(31, 34, 6, 48, 36, 46, 20, 45, 49, 8, 40, 
28, 14, 13, 22, 30, 21, 15, 8, 16, 22, 47, 31, 27, 25, 43, 9, 
24, 20, 7, 48, 10, 48, 18, 44, 26, 43, 39, 44, 41, 20, 36, 43, 
4, 30, 16, 41, 2, 49, 25, 43, 5, 31, 15, 16, 20, 11, 16, 20, 
14, 48, 26, 44, 4, 29, 42, 41, 14, 47, 21, 25, 11, 41, 20, 48, 
35, 4, 42, 19, 8, 34, 23, 39, 25, 11, 29, 24, 31, 9, 20, 6, 45, 
46, 23, 32, 12, 23, 11, 7, 39), Binary = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), IndID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Int", 
"Time", "Binary", "IndID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))

head(Matrix)
  Int Time Binary IndID
1   1   31      1   AAA
2   1   34      1   BBB
3   1    6      1   CCC
4   1   48      1   DDD
5   1   36      1   AAA
6   1   46      1   BBB
```

Matrix has 100 rows and 4 columns.  The first three columns are needed for mathematics.  The 4th column is used as an ID.  I want to multiply the vector matrix (below) to the first three columns of the larger Matrix for each individual.

Here is the vector matrix...

```
coef <- c(-0.13731791, -0.01122941, 0.65487107)
coef <- as.matrix(coef)
coef
```

I am trying to use the code below.

```
Matrix[Matrix$IndID=="AAA", c(1,2,3)] %*% coef
```

In words: multiply columns 1:3 of Matrix by coef when the IndID row contains “AAA”.  This results in the following error.

```
"Error in Matrix[Matrix$IndID == "AAA", c(1, 2, 3)] %*% coef : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"
```

I also tried to combine two conditionals into the columns conditional using the & operator as I had seen on other SO posts.  That code and the resulting error are below.

```
Matrix[,(Matrix$IndID=="AAA") & (c(1,2,3))] %*% coef 

Error in `[.data.frame`(Matrix, , (Matrix$IndID == "AAA") & (c(1, 2, 3))) : 
  undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In (Matrix$IndID == "AAA") & (c(1, 2, 3)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

These data are a sample of my actual data where I am trying to add these functions into a larger `for()` loop with many individuals.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

`Matrix` is a data frame, not a matrix.  You can coerce the subset of `Matrix` you want to do math on with `as.matrix()`.  Try:

```
as.matrix(Matrix[Matrix$IndID=="AAA", c(1,2,3)]) %*% coef
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  Your code above still results in an an error, but pointing out the incorrect classification of Matrix (my obvious over site) was very helpful.  I was able to preform my task by correctly classifying Matrix as a matrix with only numbers and making a separate IndID object.  I could then run Matrix[IndID=="AAA",] %*% coefM[["AAA"]] which preforms the matrix multiplication when the IndID's are equal.